# looping custom cursor opacity falling in infinite loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, opacity

I am trying to make my custom cursor glow slowly by changing its opacity. The problem is that the only way I can see it working is by making a `while`, which creates an infinite loop. Is there a way to proceed so my cursor changes from 0 opacity to 1 opacity and go up and down. Here is my code at the moment... I'm trying to find another way to proceed, but I really don't see any other way.

```
public var Alpha:Number = 1;
public var sense:String = "down";

private function thisMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void{


        Mouse.hide();

        //draws the cursor
        drawCursor();

        //Animates cursor
        if(!this.animationStarted)
        {
            this.animationStarted = true;
            animateCursor();
        }


    }

private function animateCursor():void{
        while(this.animationStarted)
        {
            if(this.Alpha==1)
            {
                this.sense = "down";
            }
            else if(this.Alpha == 0)
            {
                this.sense = "up";
            }

            if(this.sense == "up")
                this.Alpha += 0.1;
            else
                this.Alpha -= 0.1;

            this.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
            this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
            this.graphics.endFill();

            drawCursor();
        }
    }

private function drawCursor():void{
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x00BFFF,this.Alpha);
        //top left
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,6,2);
        //bottom left
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,23,6,2);
        //left top
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,2,6);
        //left bottom
        this.graphics.drawRect(0,19,2,6);
        //top righ
        this.graphics.drawRect(19,0,6,2);
        //right top
        this.graphics.drawRect(23,0,2,6);
        //bottom right
        this.graphics.drawRect(19,23,6,2);
        //right bottom
        this.graphics.drawRect(23,19,2,6);
        this.graphics.endFill();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use tweener, my favorite is [GTween](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/#download):

```
private function test():void
{
    var shape:Shape = new Shape();
    addChild(shape);

    shape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
    shape.graphics.drawCircle(100, 100, 50);
    shape.graphics.endFill();

    var tween:GTween = new GTween(shape, 1, {alpha:0}, {reflect:true, repeatCount:2});
    tween.nextTween = tween;

}
```

Use `tween.paused = true/false` to play()/stop() the tween.

There is another variant without tweener (but I recommend to use tween because code is more clear, readable and it's less resources cost) that is more like your, but instead of while loop use EnterFrame event approach - remove while loop from `animateCursor()` method, add `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener in the point of `animateCursor();` call:

```
if(!this.animationStarted)
{
     this.animationStarted = true;
     addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
} 

private function onEnterFrame():void
{
    animateCursor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid your problem with the infinite loop is to put your animateCursor code inside an ENTER_FRAME event handler.

Here's how it can look: http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1360303185

( Your custom cursor shape looks awesome ; )

Here's your code remade in MiniBuilder ( functions are arranged alphabetically ):

```
package com.glowingcursor {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.*;
import flash.ui.*;

public class Application extends Sprite {
    private var cursor:Sprite;
    private var cursorOffset:Point;
    private var sense:Boolean;

    public function 
    Application() {
        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded );
    }

    private function 
    animateCursor( e:Event ):void {
        if ( cursor.alpha >= 1 ) sense = false;
        else if ( cursor.alpha <= 0.2 ) sense = true;

        if( sense ) cursor.alpha += 0.08;
        else cursor.alpha -= 0.08;
    }

    private function
    hideCursor( e:MouseEvent ):void {
        Mouse.show();
        removeChild( cursor );
        removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCursor );
        removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateCursor );
    }

    private function
    initCursor():void {
        cursor = new Sprite();
        cursor.graphics.beginFill( 0xff0000 );
        cursor.graphics.drawRect(  0,  0, 6, 2 ); // top left
        cursor.graphics.drawRect(  0, 23, 6, 2 ); // bottom left
        cursor.graphics.drawRect(  0,  0, 2, 6 ); // left top
        cursor.graphics.drawRect(  0, 19, 2, 6 ); // left bottom
        cursor.graphics.drawRect( 19,  0, 6, 2 ); // top right
        cursor.graphics.drawRect( 23,  0, 2, 6 ); // right top
        cursor.graphics.drawRect( 19, 23, 6, 2 ); // bottom right
        cursor.graphics.drawRect( 23, 19, 2, 6 ); // right bottom
        cursor.graphics.endFill();

        // So InteractiveObjects react to the custom cursor properly
        cursor.mouseEnabled = false;

        // For cursor centering
        cursorOffset = new Point( cursor.width / 2, cursor.height / 2 );
    }

    private function 
    moveCursor( e:Event ):void {
        cursor.x = mouseX - cursorOffset.x;
        cursor.y = mouseY - cursorOffset.y;
    }

    private function
    onAdded( e:Event ):void {
        initCursor();
        showCursor();
    }

    private function
    showCursor():void {
        Mouse.hide();
        addChild( cursor );
        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCursor );
        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateCursor );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code from the animateCursor inside a different method, and use a Timer to call that method. This way you can control how "fast" the cursor blinks and when.

```
Timer timer = new Timer( 25, 0 );

private function animateCursor():void
{
    timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler );
    timer.start()
}
private function timerListener( e:TimerEvent ):void
{
    if(this.Alpha==1)
    {
       this.sense = "down";
    }
    else if(this.Alpha == 0)
    {
       this.sense = "up";
    }

    if(this.sense == "up")
       this.Alpha += 0.1;
    else
       this.Alpha -= 0.1;

    this.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
    this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
    this.graphics.endFill();

    drawCursor();
}
```

also it's a good idea to change your alpha conditions from this.Alpha == 0 to this.Alpha <= 0 as you may choose to change the amount by which you modify the alpha to values that don't always add up to 0 or 1.